# How to distinguish between keywords of user's search input?

Tags: mysql

I'm working on this project for homework. The idea is to build a site similar to Netflix.

My task is to:

```
On the "Searching" page, the customer can search for movies by any of the following attributes or their combination (logical "AND" operation):
title;
year;
director;
star's first name and/or last name. This means you need to do both: a) first name or last name if only one of the two names is provided; b) first name and last name, if both names are provided.
```

I need to query my MySQL database for all movies, actors, etc matching their query and spit it back out on my website. I'm wondering what's the best way to distinguish between the keywords of the user's search input. My initial thoughts are to just delimit the user's search keywords by white spaces, and then try to match them with each column in the MySQL table.

For example, if the user searches **"Frozen Idina Menzel"** I'll first parse their search into individual words **"Frozen", "Idina", "Menzel"** and I'd say something like

```
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title = 'Frozen' UNION
SELECT * FROM stars WHERE first_name = 'Frozen' UNION
SELECT * FROM stars WHERE last_name = 'Frozen' UNION
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title = 'Idina' UNION
SELECT * FROM stars WHERE first_name = 'Idina' UNION
SELECT * FROM stars WHERE last_name = 'Idina' UNION
SELECT * FROM movies WHERE title = 'Menzel' UNION
SELECT * FROM stars WHERE first_name = 'Menzel' UNION
SELECT * FROM stars WHERE last_name = 'Menzel'
SELECT * FROM stars WHERE first_name = 'Frozen' AND last_name = 'Idina';
SELECT * FROM stars WHERE first_name = 'Idina' AND last_name = 'Menzel';
```

However, this doesn't seem like a very good approach as there are a lot of unnecessary queries, so I was wondering if there's a better way to do this.

Comment: Have you ever heard of Full text search? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full text search, either the one build in MySQL or something external.

[MySQL Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

[Sphinx Search](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

[ElasticSearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/)

There are many tools available for your task...

Answer (score 1):

How you approach this depends on how much time you've left yourself to finish the project. ElasticSearch is extremely simple to [download](https://download.elasticsearch.org/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-0.90.10.zip) and get up on running irrespective of platform.

ElasticSearch is an [Inverted Index](http://blog.smeef.co.uk/elasticsearch-data-structure/) Search Tool, based upon Apache Lucene. You could implement an ElasticSearch solution pretty quickly if you read the right material first. Data is analyzed at index time, you can apply tokenizers and filters to define how you want your index to look. I you have a movie called " The Shawshank Redemption" and you had defined a standard tokenizer, this would create an index with the following terms and in lowercase - "shawshank" and "redemption", note that the "The" has disappeared as this is a stop word.

A good DSL Query language is used by ElasticSearch with a lot of documentation. Even if you don't use it for this project, consider it for others.

Note - Netflix also suggests as you type. ElasticSearch can do this.